# Soldier's Joy - sleeve notes appear to contradict the instruments heard on the track

Tags: bluegrass

I've been listening to [Soldier's Joy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soldier%27s_Joy_(fiddle_tune)) from [Nitty Gritty Dirt Band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitty_Gritty_Dirt_Band)'s [Dirt, Silver and Gold album](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirt,_Silver_and_Gold). It was originally on the album [Will the Circle be Unbroken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Will_the_Circle_be_Unbroken_(Nitty_Gritty_Dirt_Band_album)). Could someone please help identify the instruments and musicians on the song? I think I'm hearing in the song three instruments - two banjos and a finger-bass. According to the album info, this should be [Earl Scruggs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earl_Scruggs) on one banjo, and [John McEuen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_McEuen) on the other.

- The banjos sound different, one brighter than the other. McEuen is supposed to be on [Uncle Dave Macon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncle_Dave_Macon)'s banjo. Is Scruggs' the brighter one?
- What is history of Macon's banjo  ? (type, current owner) ?
- Who's on the bass?
- Where was this recorded?

Any other info would be appreciated.

Comment: According to the liner notes on my copy, it was recorded at Woodland Sound Studios, Nashville, Tennessee, USA.

Comment: as luck would have it, Uncle Dave Macon's banjo is smart enough to have its own [web page](https://www.birthplaceofcountrymusic.org/instrument-interview-uncle-dave-macons-banjo/)

Comment: @Angst Dang, that's amazing.

Comment: If you were to trim out the questions which require the answers in the 2 above comments, no-one could say the question is too broad, it is then about the difference between what the sleeve notes say about the musicians on the track, and what you hear.